# In TypeScript - I am trying to find the sum with input tags With React?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working with TypeScript and React. I have a form where you add numbers in and it calculates the hours at the end the total. I have 8 different input fields one can change. I went ahead and added id="" in order to add the Id to this field. Is there a different way in order to do this in order to calculate the sums?

```
  <div className="day___tonight">
        <Field
          name={quanity1}
          component={component1}
          id="qty"
          type="number"
          validate={valuesMax}
        />
      </div>
```

I am having trouble with the correct ES6/TypeScript syntax for how to do this. This is what I am wanting to do.

```
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
```

The question is how to calculate say the input tags in TypeScript.

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: what is the html type element for <Field>

Comment: I am asking what the correct way to calculate say the sum of input tags in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the DOM like you suggest is a big anti-pattern in React, Angular, Vue etc. Any framework which abstracts away the DOM basically doesn't want you to mess with it. So what might work with vanilla JS or jQuery will not work here.

I'm not familiar with the `<Field>` component you're using. But a vanilla version would look like this:

```
interface Props {}

interface State {
   value1: number;
   value2: number;
   sum: number;
}

export class Sums extends React.Component<Props, State> {
   constructor(props: Props) {
       super(props); 
       this.state = {value1: 0, value2: 0, sum: 0};
   }

   render() {
       return (
           <div>
               <input type="number" value={this.state.value1} onChange={e => this._handleValue1(e);} />
               <input type="number" value={this.state.value2} onChange={e => this._handleValue2(e);} />
               <span>Total: {this.state.sum}</span>
           </div>
       );
   }

   private _handleValue1(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
      const val = Number.parseInt(e.currentTarget.value);
      this.setState({value1: val, sum: val + this.state.value2});
   }

   private _handleValue2(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
      const val = Number.parseInt(e.currentTarget.value);
      this.setState({value2: val, sum: val + this.state.value1});
   }
}
```

This is for just two inputs, but you can quickly generalize it for `n`, or even a variable number of them via an array.